# Chrome automatic redirect on certain pages

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

So I'm living in Germany and I have this little problem that when I google something in english the first page google finds for me is in german, which I don't want, since im specifically posting my question in english.
So googles result is, for example,

> https://example.com/de/something/somethingElse123/andSoOn/

is it somehow possible (preferably without extensions) to redirect the page automatically to

> https://example.com/us/something/somethingElse123/andSoOn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can do this as follows.

Open google, normally you get a search bar in the center.

In the page search for **Settings** and click on it.

If you are in the **Search Settings** click on Languages.

Under **Which language should Google use products?** and **Currently showing search results in :**

you can change the language to your preference.

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that settings button down there. Now it's working as it should. If I google in english I get english results and if I google in german I get german results. I still don't understand why it's working now and not before when it was just the other way around. Thank you very much